# How do I perpetuate private field data from a Component object into an Entity object using NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Lets say we have an **Entity** class that has many fields and methods but also has a **Component** object. We have kept Component data encapsulated in a separate class for an arbitrary reason.

```
    public class Entity
    {
            //...other stuff

            public virtual Component Component { get; protected set; }

            //...other stuff
    }
```

Lets say our **Component** has many responsibilities but only 3 fields all of which are **private fields**. We have kept the fields private for an arbitrary reason.

```
    public class Component
    {
         //...other stuff

         private string fieldName1 { get; set; }
         private string fieldName2 { get; set; }
         private string fieldName3 { get; set; }

         //...other stuff
    }
```

Now, lets say that our Entity corresponds with a Table in the database.
We want that table to have a column for each field on the Component.
We call them "columnName1", "columnName2", and "columnName3" respectively.

The question is:
**how can we use Fluent NHibernate to perpetuate private field data from a Component object which belongs to an Entity (that corresponds with a table in your database)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the auto mapping for your entity like this:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Automapping.Alterations;

public class EntityOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Entity>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Entity> mapping)
    {
         mapping.Component(x => x.Component, c => 
         {
               c.Map(Reveal.Member<Component>("fieldName1"),"columnName1");
               c.Map(Reveal.Member<Component>("fieldName2"),"columnName2");
               c.Map(Reveal.Member<Component>("fieldName3"),"columnName3");
         });
    }
}
```